passing 2d c array to labview
I want to create a dll that gets some data and put them in a 2d array and then pass it to labview
the problem is all I get is a pointer instead of the whole array
I allocate array in c by using malloc function and pass the array but when Test the labview shared library wizard the output gives a pointer to the array
here is how i pass the array:
   int height = 720;
   int width = 1280;

    uint8_t  *RGBarray = malloc(height * width * 3 * sizeof(uint8_t));

//and here is the function prototype:
void DLL_EXPORT __cdecl get_RGB_Array(const char*url,uint8_t** RGBarray,int* height,int* width);


how should I make 2d array in large size for storing rgb data of a video frame and pass it so in the labview shared library wizard I get a 2d array as out put not a pointer to that 2d array?
even if you can guide me for doing this with a 1d array its ok.
I expect to pass a 2d array in my dll so labview can recognize it
and i can't understand why stackoverflow keeps telling that this question is duplicated. i saw them. none of them were nearly related to labview shared libraries like this one

no it is not the same. my array is so large and i am working with labview too. i explained it in my question

Please specify, how do you think, the size of the array is affecting the behaviour in any way? And in C, you always get a pointer to the first element of the array if you pass an array to a function.

because the rgb data is large i can't statically allocate memory for the array so i need to use pointers more often and i think that's why in labivew shared library wizard my exported function are not recognized with the function prototype i want

The **-thing is not a 2D array. This anti-pattern continues to pop-up for decades.

As I mentioned, passing an array to a function always happens by passing a pointer to the first element of that array. It does not matter whether the memory for that array is located on the stack or allocated via malloc. The pointer does not care where it points to .

Do you have to call that get_RGB_Array function or do you have to provide it?

A 2D array can be either an array of arrays or an array of pointers to arrays. ** means the latter.

I tested different methods for creating the array and i have to use malloc and pointer because the array data is too large to be allocated statically.
my problem is more related to labview shared libraries, how i make the array and pass it so in the shared library wizard the function prototype be recognized correctly
the closest i got is returning a pointer to array memory block but i want to return the array itself

@stark, it can also be a pointer to whole array int (*)[rows][cols] or a pointer to its first row int(*)[cols].

good point, but if i am making the array like this:
int arr;
arr=malloc(50sizeof(int8_t));
arr it self is a pointer to array right
but when I am working with labview shared library wizard I get only the array address not the array itself in function prototype

The LabVIEW dll wizard isn't much use. I have asked a moderator to review this being closed so I can submit a proper answer but in the meantime, I have uploaded one possible solution to your question here https://gist.github.com/j-medland/e3a15f3e21e73c1d3fc8f594356a5ef3
